# knockout computed observable write not working for plain object containing atomic observables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, computed-observable

I have created a computed observable from simple observables like this:

- this.fullDetails is the computed observable.
- this.computeFullDetails is the computed's read function.
- this.writeToComponents is the computed's write function.

When i modify the input box corresponding to the atomic observables the computed properties get modified but when i modify the computed properties,the atomic ones are not updated.
Can I get an alternative approach to get something like this done?.

#### **please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/saurabh0jha/wqpZ9/**

```
function PersonViewModel()
{
    this.firstName = ko.observable("");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("");
    this.phoneNos = ko.observable(0);
    this.address = ko.observable("");
    this.computeFullDetails = function(){
            retObj = {};
            retObj.firstName=ko.observable(this.firstName());
            retObj.lastName=ko.observable(this.lastName());
            retObj.phoneNos=ko.observable(this.phoneNos());
            retObj.address=ko.observable(this.address());
            return retObj; 
        };
    
    this.writeToComponents = function(value){
                this.firstName(value.firstName());
                this.lastName(value.lastName());
                this.phoneNos(value.phoneNos());
                this.address(value.address());
            };
        
    this.fullDetails = ko.computed(
        {
            read:this.computeFullDetails,
            write:this.writeToComponents,
        },this);

}


var vm = new PersonViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

### HTML

```
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <title>Hello, Knockout.js</title>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>atomic</h2>
    <input data-bind="value: firstName" style="display:block" />
    <input data-bind="value: lastName" style="display:block"/>
    <input data-bind="value: phoneNos"style="display:block" />
    <input data-bind="value: address" style="display:block"/>
    <h2>computed</h2>
    <input data-bind="value: fullDetails().firstName" style="display:block"/>
    <input data-bind="value:fullDetails().lastName" style="display:block"/>
    <input data-bind="value: fullDetails().phoneNos"style="display:block" />
    <input data-bind="value: fullDetails().address"style="display:block" />

    <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-2.2.0.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='2computedObservables.js'>   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please note that the bindings to the properties of `fullDetails()` such as `fullDetails().firstName` don't actually cause `writeToComponents` to fire when the textbox value changes.

Comment: That is my exact problem here .The same write back will work if the computed is calculated using string operations like this return self.firstName+ " " +self.lastName.

But when i want to write back to observables nested in object,it does not work.Dont know if there is a simple way to do it as i am not comfortable writing custom bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do.

The problem with your code is that you do not subscribe to the observables you return in `computeFullDetails`.

You can try this:

```
<input data-bind="value: fullDetailsFirstName" style="display:block" />

this.fullDetailsFirstName = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return self.firstName();
    },
    write: function (newValue) {
        self.firstName(newValue)
    }
});
```

Example (changed only firstName): 
http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/VJ4th/1/

Comment: Sorry for not making things clear .. 
I am trying to pick up atomic properties from one page,make an AJAX call with those inputs and when the call returns update another page.For simplicity i have created the above example by putting both the pages in single one. 

i am using the computed observable and converting to JS as request for the AJAX and using the response to update the computed observable.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```js
retObj.firstName=ko.observable(this.firstName());
```

creates a *new* observable with the value of the old one. Because of this, you lose all the old dependencies every time `computeFullDetails` is called.

Everything that was bound to a previous `fullDetails().firstName` will never be updated again.

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
function PersonViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("");
    this.lastName  = ko.observable("");
    this.phoneNos  = ko.observable(0);
    this.address   = ko.observable("");

    this.anyAttribute = ko.computed(function() {
      this.firstName();
      this.lastName();
      this.phoneNos();
      this.address();

      // what this returns is not important, its
      // only job is to notify subscribers when any
      // dependency has changed
    });

    this.anyAttribute.subscribe(function() {
      // do here whatever you need to do when any
      // of the attributes has changed
    });
}

var vm = new PersonViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```